# Error in installing .NET Core 1.0.0 - VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I installed Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 and tried to install .NET Core 1.0.0 - VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2 in order to start developments on .Net core. however setup failed with following error message.

[[image: Error Message]]

I tried with **SKIP_VSU_CHECK=1** as well. But didn't work. I am using windows 7 (64 bit) operating system.
Any help on this matter is highly appreciated.

Comment: You still got this error dialog after `SKIP_VSU_CHECK=1`?

Comment: Download a new copy of it, sounds like corrupted setup to me

Comment: Have you looked into the logfile? What is its content?

Comment: Try to move setup in *separate directory* where no other files (especially old setups) exist and retry the installation.

Comment: Moving setup in to a different location also didnt work for me

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the setup have the same problem like ASP.NET 5 RC1 setup. I recommend you to try to move the setup in **separate directory**, where no other files (especially no old MSI setups) exist and retry the installation. See [the issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1085) ([the comment and later](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1085#issuecomment-157787917)) and [the old post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2014/05/01/incorrect-hash-value-when-installing-visual-studio-2013-update-2/) which describe close errors in old setups.